# Classes without default constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

Can we create an array of objects of the class not having default constructor, if yes then can anyone elaborate on how can we do this?

For following class for Abc a[10] in main(); is generating compiler error 
'no matching function for call to `Abc::Abc()'

```
class Abc{
    private: 
           int x;
    public:
           Abc(int a){
           x = a;
           }
};

int main(){
    Abc a[10]; // Compilation would fail here, as it would look for default constructor
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can we create an array of objects of the class not having default constructor?

Yes, you can. You have to call one of the available constructors to initialize each of the members of the array. The only way to do that is to initialize the array with an initialization list:

```
Abc a[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

In this case, it is enough to put integers in the array, because your `Abc` constructor is not explicit. This means you can do this:

```
Abc a = 42; // Calls A(42)
```

If it were explicit, you would have to say

```
Abc a[10] = { Abc(1), Abc(2), ..... };
```

Obviously this dosn't scale well, but it works OK for small arrays.

Comment: This is not the only way. Look at my answer at the bottom.

Comment: @Krypton No this isn't the only way. But it has the virtue of not producing undefined behaviour.

Comment: I don't want to keep arguing for nothing. I will just keep my downvote as long as I see "The only way to do..."

Comment: @Krypton It is the only way to initialize an *array* of *objects* of a certain type. Your answer doesn't even do that.

Comment: Well, I really don't want to argue with u. Can you please read the question again? "Can we create an array of objects of the class not having default constructor" The OP didn't even mention that he wants to intialize. While my answer doesn't even do that, but I know it can. I didn't want to add as the OP did not ask for it.

Comment: Not sure if we need another answer or you just want to add it to yours but you can also use `Abc a[10](x);` where each instance in the array will be constructed with `x`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not sure about that. Do you have a typo in that code? Should produce `array initializer must be an initializer list`.

Comment: @juanchopanza That is interesting.  I wonder which one is correct.  I was always under the impression `array_name[size](value)` called the constructor for each element in the array with the `value` provided.  Maybe it is a extension.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if you define a constructor, of any kind, the compiler will not automatically generate a default constructor. You have to do it manually.

Comment: That was a typo while writing a question, Constructor is named Abc.

Comment: @Shrikant It's a constructor, but it's not a [*default* constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).